# The BootstrapTable is not rendering

Tags: reactjs

could anyone please check my code and tell me what am i doing wrong or what have I missed? I have just started with React and I switch from using simple tables to react-bootstrap-tables

https://codepen.io/mnshrt/pen/ebBwKp

```
   function DetailsTable(props){
     return(
         <ul>
                  <BootstrapTable data={props.vehicleModel}>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="year">{detailHeadersList[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="model">{detailHeadersList[1]}</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price">{detailHeadersList[2]}</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="buy">{detailHeadersList[3]}</TableHeaderColumn>
                  </BootstrapTable>
        </ul>
    )
     }


    earlier it was
    function DetailsTable(props){
     return(
         <ul>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>{detailHeadersList[0]}</th>
                    <th>{detailHeadersList[1]}</th>
                    <th>{detailHeadersList[2]}</th>
                    <th>{detailHeadersList[3]}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{props.vehicleModel.year}</td>
                    <td>{props.vehicleModel.model}</td>
                    <td>{props.vehicleModel.price}</td>
                    <td><button>Buy Now</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ul>
    )
```

Comment: Please post your full file. You might not be importing things right.

Comment: I am doing this on codepen. So the imports are in the settings->javascript tab.Kindly check the link provided.https://codepen.io/mnshrt/pen/ebBwKp